# Library with provided scope still exists in the jar

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I added the Lombok library to my project:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <version>1.18.16</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Even with *provided* scope, this library exists in the `jar`. I tried this option:

```xml
<optional>true</optional>
```

But the result is the same - I have the Lombok library in my jar. I have other libraries that should be removed from the jar. I always thought that I should use *provided* scope for this purpose, but it doesn't work for me.

Full pom:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>test</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.16</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Your understanding of "provided" is correct. By using the info you provided we can by no means tell what the problem could be. Could you at least show us the whole pom file?

Comment: @ Philipp I added full pom

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Spring Boot Maven Plugin will still package Lombok, even if its scope is provided. However, you can easily exclude dependencies, see [Spring Boot Maven Plugin Documentation: Dependency Exlusion](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.3.x/maven-plugin/reference/html/#repackage-example-exclude-dependency)

So try adding following configuration to the plugin:

```
<configuration>
    <excludes>
        <exclude>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </exclude>
    </excludes>
</configuration>
```

Comment: ok, what about `<groupId>com.github.spotbugs</groupId>`? Should I add this library to exclude too?

Comment: Yes, add an "exclude" tag for any dependency you don't want to be packaged

Comment: It is unobvious behavior.  Minus one point to spring. But answer correct +1